# passing an object( field value ) into view and save it on a model

Tags: django

I have a field called 'rep' in my form, I want the view ,query the user that is equal to 'rep' and 
pass it to my view and save it into the recipient in the model :

I tried the following line :
  form.instance.recipient = Message.objects.get(recipient=self.request.rep)

but 
I get

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'rep'
```

View :

## view.py

class compose(CreateView):

```
model = Message
form_class=ComposeForm
template_name='django_messages/compose.html'


def form_valid(self,form):
 #   form.instance.recipient = Message.objects.get(recipient=self.request.rep)
    form.instance.sender =self.request.user
    return super(compose,self).form_valid(form)
```

form.py

```
   class ComposeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        """
        A simple default form for private messages.

        """

        class Meta:
           model = Message
          # fields ='__all__'
           fields=['rep','subject','body',]

        #recipient = CommaSeparatedUserField(label=_(u"Recipient"))
      #  subject = forms.CharField(label=_(u"Subject"), max_length=140)
      #  subject='hello'
        body = forms.CharField(label=_(u"Body"),
            widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '12', 'cols':'55'}))
        rep=forms.CharField()
```

## model.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    A private message from user to user
    """
    subject = models.CharField(_("Subject"), max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField(_("Body"))
    sender = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='sent_messages', verbose_name=_("Sender"), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='received_messages', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Recipient"), on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    parent_msg = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='next_messages', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Parent message"), on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(_("sent at"), null=True, blank=True)
    read_at = models.DateTimeField(_("read at"), null=True, blank=True)
    replied_at = models.DateTimeField(_("replied at"), null=True, blank=True)
    sender_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Sender deleted at"), null=True, blank=True)
    recipient_deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Recipient deleted at"), null=True, blank=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYxCB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view check if the form is_valid, if it is you can access the form data as shown below.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.cleaned_data['rep']
```

You can still access the unvalidated data directly from request.POST at this point, but the validated data is better.

The Django documentation has a similar example in the docs
[Django docs | Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'rep'
```

The reason for this error is the `request` object does not have the form data within it directly, it is saved in the `POST` key.

Comment: Issues an error I even tried :
  form.instance.recipient =settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(user=self.request.POST.get('rep'))

Comment: I have updated my answer, with an alternative solution

Comment: it worked, but I change the model to :
        recipient=form.cleaned_data['rep']
        
        User = get_user_model()
        form.instance.recipient =User.objects.get(username=recipient)

Comment: Thats great! I'm happy it solved your problem, do consider marking the question as solved,  if others have the same question, maybe we can help them :) All the best and happy coding :)